# How to make card size according to material design in android?

Tags: android

I have a `listview` in activity containing `card view` with one `image`, and `text`.

I want to make dimension of card view according to material design. How can I do that? Could somebody help and kindly point out what I need to change in my code according to material design?

Here is my code so far:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:id="@+id/card_view"
                                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                android:background="#424767"
                                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                                card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius"
                                card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/card_elevation">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/appImage"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/subHeadingText"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headingText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/appImage"
            android:paddingLeft="16sp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="24sp"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subHeaderText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/headingText"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/appImage"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:text="14sp"
            android:textColor="#000"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subHeadingText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/subHeaderText"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/appImage"
            android:lines="4"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:text="@string/stories_detail"
            android:textColor="#737078"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/getDealBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/get_deal_button"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFF"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[And here is my Image for this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C27bp.png)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you should use something like this and design your accordingly. run to see affect

[image]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Check in"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCheckInTime"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="9:20AM"/>

        <View

            android:id="@+id/viewStatus"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@color/clrPresent"
            />


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: is it helpful for you. you just need to set your card layout propertie properly.